# tasks namespace missing from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I am currently developing a vscode extension and would like to implement a taskprovider in order to make some global tasks that come with the extension.

My problem is that the tasks namespace does not appear in the autocomplete along with window,scm, workspace and others. This makes the typescript shout an error ofcourse.

Has anyone encountered this before? As you can see, its clearly not finding the tasks namespace.

[image]

Best regards.

Comment: In your `package.json`, what vs code version is listed under the `engines` section?

Comment: @MattBierner "vscode": "^1.15.0"

Comment: Try upgrading it to `^1.23.0` and running npm install again

Comment: Just tried it and the problem persists.